# reading fstab to mount sshfs in container

Tags: linux, mount, docker, alpine-linux

I'm using Docker to create an image from `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`  and trying to mount a remote folder using sshfs + fuse. in order to do that I run the container with `docker run -d --rm --device /dev/fuse --privileged my_container`

the code in the Dockerfile I put the following lines:

```
RUN echo "sshfs#myuser@${host}:${folder} $mount_folder fuse allow_other,default_permissions,umask=0007,idmap=file,uidfile=/etc/sshfs_umap,gidfile=/etc/sshfs_gmap,nomap=ignore,StrictHostKeyChecking=no,IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa   0       0" >> /etc/fstab
```

this line basically add to /etc/fstab the command to mount remote folder using sshfs.
when I access the container, I can't see the files in my `mount_folder`, but when i manually run

`$mount -a`

the folder is successfully mounted.
how can I make this automatically mounted when container starts?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, 
instead of running the following Dockerfile run command:

```
RUN echo "sshfs#myuser@${host}:${folder} $mount_folder fuse allow_other,default_permissions,umask=0007,idmap=file,uidfile=/etc/sshfs_umap,gidfile=/etc/sshfs_gmap,nomap=ignore,StrictHostKeyChecking=no,IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa   0       0" >> /etc/fstab
```

I delete it, and added CMD command in dockerfile that runs a .sh script and contains the line:

```
#!/bin/sh
sshfs -o allow_other -o reconnect -o default_permissions -o 'umask=0007' -o 'idmap=file' -o 'uidfile=/etc/sshfs_umap' -o 'gidfile=/etc/sshfs_gmap' -o 'nomap=ignore' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -o 'IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa' myuser@$SFTP_HOST:$SFTP_ROOT_FOLDER /myfolder

#do tother things here to run your app
```

This mount the remote file system every time the docker container runs. I guess the reason why /etc/fstab didn't run, is probably because the container is not really booting up from scrach, because it is a container... so /etc/fstab never run...

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -it --rm debian cat /etc/fstab
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
failed to resize tty, using default size
```

I didn't even know you could change the fstab for a Docker container but also I'm a bit at a loss for why you would; docker typically handles mounting of filesystems and there is even a volume driver / plugin for SSHFS that handles all of this for you:

```
docker plugin install vieux/sshfs
Plugin "vieux/sshfs" is requesting the following privileges:
 - network: [host]
 - mount: [/var/lib/docker/plugins/]
 - mount: []
 - device: [/dev/fuse]
 - capabilities: [CAP_SYS_ADMIN]
Do you grant the above permissions? [y/N] y
latest: Pulling from vieux/sshfs
Digest: sha256:1d3c3e42c12138da5ef7873b97f7f32cf99fb6edde75fa4f0bcf9ed277855811
52d435ada6a4: Complete 
Installed plugin vieux/sshfs

docker volume create -d vieux/sshfs -o sshcmd=root@localhost:/srv/ -o password=changeme mysshvol

docker run -it --rm -v mysshvol:/mnt debian
```

Any reason why you wouldn't do it that way? In my experience it's best to leave volume mounts / mapping to Docker unless you're actually developing a volume driver / plugin for docker otherwise it's a lot of extra hassle and extra dependencies that you won't otherwise need for your containers to mount a particular filesystem to the container.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to read the host's fstab? You can certainly do that but again you shouldn't need to because if the host has already mounted the sshfs somewhere you can just map a local directory into the container; although that doesn't work in some circumstances like with swarms / stack configurations but for the former you would just do docker run -it --rm -v /path/to/sshfs/mount/on/host:/mnt/ debian ..